# How to stop an SMS message thread from being a "conversation" in Android 10?

Tags: sms, android-10

I have noticed today that in the SMS Messages app on Android 10, it's very easy to add someone to the "conversations" feature which enables contact-specific message and notification settings by clicking on the thread in question, clicking on the ellipses in the top right, then Details. The thread is then a "conversation". It is very easy to do this by mistake. I do not want specific messaging options for specific contacts.

On Android 11 a contact can easily be stopped from being a "conversation" by going to:

Messages thread > vertical ellipses ⋮ > Open Details > Click Notifications > Click "This is a conversation"

However, in Android 10 the "this is a conversation" option does not exist.

How does one remove a thread from being in a "conversation" on Android 10?

EDIT: This is for a Sony Xperia 10 II, the app in question is the [standard Google messaging app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging).

Comment: Just to make sure this is not something that's customized by the vendor, consider mentioning the device model and the name/package of the SMS Messages app (I'm currently assuming it's the [Google's one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging))

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks Andrew, updated.